# OAuth2 Implicit Flow and silent autologin by Windows Identity. Possible new attack vectors?

Tags: oauth2, openid-connect

We have a typical Single-Page js application that authenticates to our own authentication server using the OAuth 2.0 protocol (and the OpenId-Connect add-in). The customer sent a request to implement silent authentication using Windows authentication (e.g. Active Directory) for intranet users. We want to implement auto-authentication of the user in the client application using a hidden xframe in which the windows-authentication page of the authentication server will be loaded. In this case, we skip the steps of entering the user's credentials on the login page and consent page. We want to be sure that we did not create a vulnerability and did not increase the attack surface of our authentication system. I'm not a very experienced security expert, so I'm asking you for help in analytics.

We do not have free registration of client applications, all applications are controlled by us.

Comment: What interface(s) are you most worried about?

Comment: @TomK. I'm worried about the system's compliance with the Oauth / openId-connect protocols. And I'm worried that this innovation can open a way to intercept the access token. If I understand your question correctly.